# Rails, Heroku - configuring 123-reg domain for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I am trying to figure out how to point my domain, which is registered with 123-reg to my heroku app.

Currently, when I check whether the steps I have taken have worked, I get an error that says:

```
Host www.example.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

Heroku has instructions for GoDaddy. I use 123-reg. 123-reg don't have any support for heroku but they do have instructions for adding CNAME records to my DNS. I've followed them.

I made three CNAME entries (and removed all A records as it appears that Heroku does not accept them).

```
www
CNAME           www.example.com.          
www
CNAME           example.com.          
www
CNAME           rainbow-mutiny-636...
```

All CNAME records have the trailing "."

Can anyone help with instructions for how to get started with 123-reg domain name configuration for heroku?

Comment: Without your real domain name this is hard to debug.

Comment: Why? other domain name providers have instructions for how to configure the DNS.

Comment: well SERVFAIL is dns error, given the real domain name, we could debug the dns call tree to see where it is, but in looking at your cnames, it look like you have loop.  , you should only have 1 CNAME,  www.your-domain CNAME  rainbow-mutiny-636, and alas you cannot have create a cname from the domain literal ie you cannot example.com CNAME rainbow-mutiny-636.

Comment: ok - i misread the heroku instructions which show the 3rd entry (but that's for when you get to adding ssl). I still get servfail errors. I'm looking for config instructions to show what the setup needs to be for 123-reg. I've found and tried the instructions for each of GoDaddy and NameCheap. If I can't figure it out, I'll need to look into how I move to one of these dns registrants so that I can move forward.

Comment: well there shouldn't be any special configuration persea.  Just use the dns manager to create the required records. You should only need the cname to your herokup app name.  Then if 123-43g has a domain forwarding you can forward the bare domain (example.com) to www.example.com so the cname for www will work.

Comment: The instructions for GoDaddy are different to those for Namecheap.

Comment: I would love to know why people vote this down. But no where near as much as I would love to find someone who uses 123-reg with a rails app hosted on heroku that might be able to help me figure out how to configure my DNS to get my app up. Thanks to anyone who has something constructive to add. I really don't understand down votes without reasons. I learn nothing about what might be offensive about this question.

Comment: can you post links to both sets of instructions. I'll try to see what the differences are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you have conflicting CNAME entries. Start by removing all CNAME entries where the hostname is "www".

Then create one new CNAME entry. The hostname field should be "www" and the Destination CNAME should be your Heroku app hostname "rainbow-mutiny-636.herokuapp.com".

Now go to your Rails app directory and run `heroku domains` in the terminal. If you've previously set it up properly you should see something like:

```
Domain Name                DNS Target
─────────────────────────  ─────────────────────
www.example.com            rainbow-mutiny-636.herokuapp.com
```

If you don't see this entry, then create it by running:

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

And that's it.  Once the DNS changes have propagated `http://www.example.com` should point to your Heroku app.

Comment: I can't actually tell if this works yet. I can see that host www.mycustomdomain.com points to my heroku name, but I can't actually navigate to the page by the custom domain name yet because I can't figure out how to add SSL to my heroku page.

Comment: thanks anyway for this  help. Ill come back to check if its working when I solve the SSL problem.

Comment: thanks anyway for the help. I still can't get this working (I have now resolved the SSL issue) but when I try to open the page using the custom address I get an error that says: This site can’t be reached

 server DNS address could not be found.

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED